# How does an SSD improve gaming performance?

Tags: hardware, performance, hard-drive

How would an SSD improve my gaming performance? Is there any FPS increment after using SSD instead of HDD?

My System Configuration

- Windows 7 Professional
- Intel Core i7 3770
- 8GB Ram
- EVGA GTX 980
- ASRock Professional M Motherboard
- HDD 2TB (1TB+1TB)

Comment: How much of an improvement you get would depend *greatly* on what the rest of your computer is.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: SSD's improve loading speeds.. not really much else and are actually horrible for disk caches if games use them. They are not directly tied to FPS

Comment: @James this sounds like an answer :)

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster Didnt feel like giving a detailed answer to a 'Loading and No' answer :D

Comment: @James I understand XD

Comment: @Close Voters - Please read the close reasons. This may be a 'bad question' but it isn't *'Too Broad'*. You should *downvote* when a question does not show any research effort or is unclear or not useful, as per the tooltip when hovering over the downvote button. Remember, [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik It might also be worth pointing out that you, as a reviewer, should be assuming good faith on the part of the close voters.  You might not be able to see the reasoning, but you shouldn't be assuming they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @James SSD are faster in most, if not all, read/write scenarios vs HDD (not as much vs hybrid HDD) so I don't see how they would be horrible as disk cache as their performance in read/write is not affected by what kind of data, or data space, they read/write...

Comment: @Frank - This is not the first question in recent times that has maybe deserved downvotes but not close votes. Do you think the question is too broad? Do you think that *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format?* Should the OP *add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs?*

Comment: @Robotnik Have you perhaps considered the close votes came in prior to the first revision? That's when mine did, and I would stand behind that vote all day long.

Comment: @Frank - The first version isn't too broad either - the only thing that has changed is the OP added some PC specs, which have not changed what the question is or how it is to be answered at all. So if you're sure that the question fits the 'too broad' criteria (and I assume you haven't retracted your vote after the revisions either), could you perhaps explain your reasons for thinking so? Because so far you haven't made that exactly clear.

Comment: @Robotnik Quite easily. Take a look at the first comment I made. How well an SSD will perform depends entirely on the rest of the computer. I don't think it's our job to explain the basics behind computer processing and what bottlenecks are.

Comment: @Frank - you don't need PC specs to know that an SSD will improve load times of things stored on it. You're right that we wouldn't know how much of an improvement, but that's not what the question is asking - it's asking How, not how much.

Comment: @Robotnik As far as gaming goes, it's irrelevant; that's a PC performance question.  Regardless, that wasn't the point of this discussion; it's your automatic assumption that people are voting incorrectly.  You don't have to agree with how someone votes.  But automatically assuming they're wrong isn't the right way to go about it; they have the privilege, they earned it.  Just because you don't agree with it doesn't make it wrong.  If you want to continue this, I can make a chat room for us.

Comment: @Frank - it's a PC performance question *in the context of gaming* - But that's my point: if you considered it off topic then you should've voted *off topic*, not *too broad*. My argument is not *don't closevote ever*, it's *vote appropriately*. No need for the chat room, Weve both made our points.

Comment: @Robotnik Both arguments make sense.  The point isn't that only a single reason counts.  But a *good faith assumption should be made*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### How do SSDs improve gaming performance?

SSDs improve performance by reducing loading times, assuming the game is installed on the SSD, of course.

#### Do they somehow impact the framerate?

It depends on the game and how they were built.

Most games use streaming to load required resources from disk when they're needed. When your disk takes too long to stream those resources, you can experience objects appearing out of nowhere (pop up), or very low quality models or textures that are suddenly replaced by higher quality ones (pop in).

Rarely, a game may wait for a resource to be fully loaded before rendering. This can cause major lags when the disk is slow, or minor stuttering (or nothing at all) when the disk is fast.

Some games (especially older ones) don't stream at all. They just make the player wait in front of a loading screen until all resources needed for the current level have been loaded. In that case, an SSD neither impacts image quality nor framerate, only the time it took before you could start playing.